# Audit Documents in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, development, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

One of our Customer wants to audit opening and downloading of documents on Sharepoint Online.I know this is not available OOB.

Is there any third party tools that we can use? Or is there any way to audit them through custom code? I can come up with a customized solution but I would like someone to put me on a right path.

Answer (score 0):

Because of storage and performance concerns, a**uditing for Opening or downloading documents**, **viewing items in lists**, or **viewing item properties** is not available for **SharePoint Online** in Office 365 for enterprises.

This option is likely to generate a large number of events that will potentially degrading the performance and other aspects of the site collection.

Sourc: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CorrelationId=03c99a70-a899-433a-a19c-c312967a8087&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

I am not aware about any code solution but you can check 3rdparties i.e Metalogix's controlPoint.